# Containers and syscall.CLONE_NEWNS

Tags: go, containers, mount, linux-namespaces

I'm running the golang code on this repo https://github.com/lizrice/containers-from-scratch/blob/master/main.go and I'm having a problem with the mount namespace. What the code should do is creating a process within its own mount namespace. So if I run the code with `sudo go run main.go run /bin/bash` and I create a file inside the directory `mytemp`, I should be able to see that file from within the new started process, but if I try to view that file moving to the rootfs directory on the host, I shouldn't be able to see that file thanks to the mount namespace.
Unfortunately I still see this file, so it seems that the process I run is not mount namespaced. 
To run the code, I used this https://github.com/ericchiang/containers-from-scratch/releases/download/v0.1.0/rootfs.tar.gz as a rootfs and moved it under `/home/me`. Then I created a `mytemp` directory to use as the tmpfs mount target. 
Do you have any ideas about the reasons why the process doesn't get mount namespaced?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue could be solved by configuring the host machine mount to be private which *does not receive or forward any propagation events to other mounts*, vide  [RedHat - Sharing Mounts](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/sect-Using_the_mount_Command-Mounting-Bind.html).

This command should be executed on your host machine before your create the container:

```
$ mount --make-rprivate /
```

Comment: Which calls the [`mount`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) syscall with `MS_PRIVATE|MS_REC` flags. This can be done [in Go](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Mount) too.

Comment: That's correct @ephemient, here's one example: `syscall.Mount("", "/", "", syscall.MS_PRIVATE|syscall.MS_REC, "")`