# How to correctly implement mount namespaces in go

Tags: linux, go, namespaces, containers, linux-namespaces

I have the following code `mnt.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Entering go program")

    cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin

    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{ 
        Cloneflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWNS,
    }

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Exiting go program")
}
```

I want to run the above code to spawn a bash shell, and run the following commands:

```
./mnt
mkdir /tmp/testmount
mount -n -o size=1m -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp/testmount
cd /tmp/testmount
touch 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

Now when I launch another shell and run the command

```
ls /tmp/testmount
```

I should not be able to see the files `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `3.txt`. Since the temp file system has been mounted inside a mount namespace, it should not be visible from the outside.

But that is not how it works for me. Why is the `syscall.CLONE_NEWNS` not working as expected? What should I do differently?

One of the comments mentions that this code works fine for them. FWIW, I am running a "bento/centos-7" Vagrant box with golang installed and no other customizations.

Comment: Actually I run your example, it works as expected. `mnt` requires `sudo` to run and after executing your commands, the three `txt` files cannot be seen from other processes (only the folder `/tmp/testmount` is accessible).

Comment: @etc-100g Very interesting. I am running this in a "bento/centos-7" vagrant box. I have no idea why it is working for you. What OS are you trying it on?

Comment: WSL2/Ubuntu 18.04. You are right, after testing on other CentOS-7/Virtualbox, the result is the same as you.

Comment: Maybe because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45524409/225692

Answer (score 0):

I was [right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936711/how-to-correctly-implement-mount-namespaces-in-go#comment104139733_58936711) about the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45524409/225692). But I did not know why. For documentation purpose, I will make this post complete.If you can read Chinese, go directly read [this Zhihu Zhuanlan post](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/166393945). That author is very professional on Linux container and docker.

The knowledge keywords are: [Shared Subtrees](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt) and [propagation types: MS_SHARED, MS_PRIVATE, and MS_SLAVE](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html). By default, system assumes you want to reuse the mounted file systems. But if you don't want that, you have to do some extra work:

> A process wants to clone its own namespace, but still wants to access the CD
> that got mounted recently.  Shared subtree semantics provide the necessary
> mechanism to accomplish the above.

On command line, you can `mount --make-rprivate /`; in code, you need to use [`syscall.MS_PRIVATE | syscall.MS_REC`](https://github.com/lizrice/containers-from-scratch/issues/3#issuecomment-347890483) to create an isolated mount.